# ModelFormSet to edit all entries for a model class

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple model class:

```
class Category(BaseModel):
    categoryText = db.StringProperty()
    parentCat = db.IntegerProperty()
```

I want to create a model formset to display all entries of category:

form class:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categoryText = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

View.py

```
def showAllCategories:
    CategoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Category)

    if request.POST:
       formset = CategoryFormSet(request.POST)
       if formset.is_valid():
           formset.save()

    else:
       formset = CategoryFormSet(Category.objects.all())
     return render_to_response('showcat.html',{'formset':formset})
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong: I get this error:
    'StringProperty' object has no attribute 'editable'

This should be really simple but it's been a challenge.

Comment: You've asked the same question three times now, and you've been told 3 times what the problem is. Try to figure out exactly what the problem is and then ask **once**

Comment: @pastylegs: Please mark as duplicate if this has been asked already.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a little bit old, but to fix your "'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'many_to_many'" error, you might want to try changing the following code:

```
CategoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(CategoryForm)
```

to

```
CategoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Category)
```

Use the name of the model instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**view.py**

```
def showAllCategories(request):
    CategoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(CategoryForm)
    if request.method=='POST':
        formset = CategoryFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            ...
            formset.save()
            ...
    else:
        formset = CategoryFormset(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

Comment: I put that attribute by mistake.  I had taken it out of my code.  Error remains.

Comment: I'm trying to create a model formset.  my understanding was that I could create a model formset to show multiple instances of Category model.  Trying to follow the django documentation, my understanding was that I have to create a model form.  Django documentation is vague;  I tried to follow model formset section.

Comment: ok, I've edited my post, notice the change of the line: CategoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Category), and the addition of **queryset** on the last line

Comment: maybe one step closer:  I get another error I don't understand:

    'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'many_to_many'

Comment: one point : I have this working with formsets.  The reason I tried to switch to model formsets was to make update code easier.  My understanding was that with formsets I had to write the code for update but with model formsets update would be done with .save() -

Comment: that's true. it does allow that. Your error is somewhere else, it looks like in the class Meta: in your ModelForm. Your models look strange, what is "BaseModel"?

Comment: I'm using google app engine with Django 1.2 - I've installed appengine helper which adds BaseModel which maps appengine datastore model to Django models.
Looks like it would have been easier to just write the code for update after POST.

Comment: just learned.  model formsets not supported with configuration I am using.  I have to update from GAE helper to GAE non-rel - Thanks for all your help.